# jquery datepicker not sending data on using .serialize() for populating the grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datepicker, submit, serialization

I have a form with 2 input type="text" , 1 combo box and other contains ( combo box contains equal , after,before & between operators + start date(jquery datepicker)+end date(jquery date picker ) but when i am sending the data to server its not appending date parameters with the url using .serialize().

My approach:

```
$("form#transactionForm").submit(function() {
    var newUrl = "/cpsb/transactionHistory.do?method=getTransactionHistoryDetails&" +
                 $(this).serialize();

    $("#transactionHistory").jqGrid(
        "setGridParam",
        {"url": newUrl, datatype:"json"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
    return false;
});
```

mark up:

```
<form class="transform" id="transactionForm" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <legend class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Transaction History</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="lpn">LPN</label>
            <input id="lpn" name="lpn"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="sku">SKU</label>
            <input id="sku" name="sku" class="skui ui-widget-content" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ttype">Transaction Type:</label>
            <select id="ttype" name="tranType" >
            <option value="">Select transaction type</option>
            <option value="100">100-Receipt</option>
            <option value="110">110-Shipment</option>
            <option value="120">120-Pallet Update</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="tdate">Transaction date:</label>
            <select id="tdate" name="date">
                <option value="equalsDate">Equal</option>
                <option>Between</option>
                <option value="beforeDate">Before</option>
                <option value="afterDate">After</option>
            </select>
            <input id="sdate" type="text"  style="width:70px"/>
            <input id="edate" type="text"  style="width:70px"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is very easy. If you want that the input fields with ids `"sdate"` and `"edate"` having `datepicker` will be serialized under the names `startDate` and `endDate` you have to modify your HTML code from

```
<input id="sdate" type="text"  style="width:70px"/>
<input id="edate" type="text"  style="width:70px"/>
```

to

```
<input id="sdate" name="startDate" type="text" style="width:70px"/>
<input id="edate" name="endDate"   type="text" style="width:70px"/>
```

The function `jQuery.serialize()` serialize only elements which has `name` attribute. All your `<select>` have `name` attribute so they are serialized.

Comment: thanks! my bad....can I disable the end date when user select other combo box options instead of between....only on selecting between operator I want to use end date ...

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, but it seems to me that you find the answer in your question. You can use `$("#edate").removeAttr('name');` to remove `name` attribute or `$("#edate").attr('name', 'startDate');` to restore it

Comment: i want to disable my second datepicker...only when user select the option "between" from drop down combo box it wil be enable to use the datepicker...

Comment: @paul: then you can bind "change" event handler to the drop-down "#tdate" (`$("#tdate").change(function() { ... }`) and if the selected item (`$("#tdate option:selected").text()`) is "Between" then show the second datepicker with `$("#edate").show()` or hide it with `$("#edate").hide()`. If you will see that `$.serialize()` will serialize hidden datepicker, then use the trick with `$("#edate").removeAttr('name')` and `$("#edate").attr('name', 'startDate')`.

Comment: @Oleg ..can I do like this  $("#tdate").change(function(){
            if(($("#tdate option:selected").text()) == Between)
            {
                $("#edate").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#edate").hide();
            }
        });  and <input id="edate" name="endDate" type="hidden"  style="width:70px;" readonly/>

Comment: @paul: It seems be OK! Only instead of `"== Between"` you should use `"=== 'Between'"` and use `readonly="readonly"` instead of only `readonly`.

Comment: but I .show() is not working ...I am not sure about it moreover I have a datepicker image icon which is also showing ...its a buttonImage..I tried to debuf it in firebug but did n't provide me with information..

Comment: @Oleg i have remove text type= "hidden" and dynamically hide using .hide() for all cases except between...so now its working ...still did n't fig out the input type hidden why not showed up using .show()..thanks!